# Dúvida inner join, left join mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Estou trabalhando com as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE livro
(     Id_livro int NOT NULL,
      Nome_livro CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
      Pg int,
      Edicao int, 
      Editora int NOT NULL,
      Assunto int NOT NULL, 
      Preco decimal (5,2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (Id_livro),
      FOREIGN KEY (Editora) REFERENCES Editora(Id_editora),
      FOREIGN KEY (Assunto) REFERENCES Assunto(Id_assunto)
) Engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE Emprestimo
(   operacao int NOT NULL,
    data_emp date NOT NULL,
    data_dev date NOT NULL,    
    cliente int, 
    livro_1 int NOT NULL, 
    livro_2 int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (operacao),
    FOREIGN KEY (cliente) REFERENCES Cliente(Id_cliente), 
    FOREIGN KEY (livro_1) REFERENCES livro(Id_livro), 
    FOREIGN KEY (livro_2) REFERENCES livro(Id_livro)
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

O que quero saber é o número de vezes que cada livro foi alugado. Para isso estou fazendo a consulta

```
select l.Nome_livro, count(emp.livro_1) as 'livro 1', count(emp2.livro_2) as 'livro 2'
from livro l 
JOIN emprestimo emp ON emp.livro_1 = l.Id_livro
left join emprestimo emp2 ON emp2.livro_2 = l.Id_livro
group by l.Nome_livro;
```

Mas o resultado parece estar multiplicando a coluna `emp2.livro_2` pela `emp.livro_1`. Por exemplo, esta é a saída que eu recebo, quando na verdade a última linha deveria ser 4 e 1 e a penúltima linha 3 e 1. Já a linha `Os Miseráveis` deveria ser 3 e 2, respectivamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi muito bem porque você criou 2 relacionamentos com a mesma tabela. Porém criei suas tabelas, preenchi e fiz um único left join e funcionou corretamente:  `select l.Nome_livro, count(emp.livro_1) as 'livro 1'
from livro l 
LEFT JOIN emprestimo emp ON emp.livro_1 = l.Id_livro
group by l.Nome_livro;`. Testa essa e detalha melhor o porque desses relacionamentos duplicados.

Comment: @InteliderSistemas Criei 2 relacionamentos porque quero fazer o count dos livros do primeiro registro e também o count dos livros armazenados no segundo registro.

Comment: Esse primeiro registro é referente ao empréstimo e o segundo a devolução, porque se não for não tem muito sentido, você tem que ter um parâmetro em cada registro para poder fazer isso, por exemplo: o primeiro item é de empréstimo o segundo de devolução. se você puder fornecer mais detalhes agradeço.

Comment: Os 2 são de empréstimo. Cada usuário pode pegar 2 livros por operação. Assim eu registro o livro 1 e o livro 2. Por isso o segundo registro pode ser null algumas vezes. Eu que agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: O que identifica o 2º empréstimo !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para quem possa estar querendo a resposta, fiz a solução não com `inner` ou `left join`, mas sim com `Union`

```
SELECT Nome_livro, count(livro_1) as 'mais retirados'
from (select nome_livro, livro_1 
    FROM emprestimo, livro
    where emprestimo.livro_1 = livro.Id_livro
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nome_livro, livro_2
    From emprestimo, livro
    where emprestimo.livro_2 = livro.Id_livro) as x
group by Nome_livro;
```